# Types conversion

Tags: python, types, type-conversion

I need to apply the type conversion to the time column and remove the last 4 symbols which are equal to ' min' and convert the rest to int.

Current code is below, just not sure how to remove the ' min' from the time column.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('https://codefinity-content-media.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/10db3746-c8ff-4c55-9ac3-4affa0b65c16/exercise.csv')

data['time'] = data['time'].apply(lambda x: _ _ _ _ _ _)
print(data.sample(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

For each value `x`, you can keep everything but the last four with `x[:-4]`. So your final code will be:

```
data['time'] = data['time'].apply(lambda x: int(x[:-4]))
```

Comment: Thank You!, I was missing the second 'x'